# Parsing nested CSS-styled text in C#

Tags: c#, css, string-parsing, css-parsing

I am expecting to have a text as a string input in C# as shown under **BEFORE_PROCESSING** title. This text needs to be formatted such that:

1. The naked sentences without any style tag (e.g. Sentence 1)must get a style tag to make the entire sentence become **bold**.
2. The sentences that are already having a style tag needs to be identified and their foreground color element must be set as **"fg:Red"** in order to make the whole sentence look in RED.
3. The sentences that are already having a style tag might have nested style tags. So, this needs to be taken into consideration.

As an example, after the formatting completed, the sentence in **BEFORE_PROCESSING** title should look like the text under **AFTER_PROCESSING**.

My question is what would be the most efficient way to realize this text processing business in C#? Would it be use of a regex or it overkills? Would you think some better alternative might exist? Thanks.

(I am using C#4)

**BEFORE_PROCESSING**

```
"Sentence 1 <style styles='B;fg:Green'>STYLED SENTENCE</style> Sentence 2"
```

**AFTER_PROCESSING**

```
"<style styles='B'>Sentence 1 </style> 
 <style styles='B;fg:Red'>STYLED  SENTENCE</style>  
 <style styles='B'>Sentence 2</style>"
```

Comment: You can mak it with a regular expression. Does "**" is the line break sequence ?

Comment: I am sorry those stars were redundant and added by mistake. I have removed them.

Comment: Can you have Sentence 1 Sentence 2 ? Waht is the end character for the sentences ? Or can we Consider the <style> tag is the sentences separator ?

Comment: There is no specific end character. This is free text in natural language. We should continue processing until the end of text is reached.

Comment: Yes, for sure the style tag is the sentence seperator...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the solution below, based on a regular expression :

```
string myLine = "Sentence 1<style styles='B;fg:Green'>STYLED SENTENCE</style>Sentence 2";
const string splitLinesRegex = @"((?<Styled>\<style[^\>]*\>[^\<\>]*\</style\>)|(?<NoStyle>[^\<\>]*))";

var splitLinesMatch = Regex.Matches(myLine, splitLinesRegex, RegexOptions.Compiled);
List<string> styledLinesBis = new List<string>();

foreach (Match item in splitLinesMatch)
{
    if (item.Length > 0)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.Groups["Styled"].Value))
            styledLinesBis.Add(string.Format("<style styles='B'>{0}</style> ", item.Groups["Styled"].Value));

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.Groups["NoStyle"].Value))
            styledLinesBis.Add(string.Format("<style styles='B;fg:Red'>{0}</style>  ", item.Groups["NoStyle"].Value));
    }
}
```

You just have to join the strings, using a string.Join statement for instance.